# Удаление нераспределенного пространства

Tags: windows, resize, proxmox

Есть нода proxmox с хранилищем /media/storage2, который используется двумя виртуальными машинами. Образы VM101 и VM103. Слишком много места было случайно увеличено на vm 101. Как теперь удалить это нераспределенное пространство на виртуальной машине с ОС Windows и освободить место в хранилище ноды без потери данных. Можно ли использовать команду:

```
qemu-img resize /media/storage2/images/101/vm-101-disk-0.raw -299G
```

и не сделает ли это хуже?
proxmox 6.1-5

[image: windows_disk]